# Is the wave function of an electron connected to the fact that it behaves as a wave near a double slit?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, double-slit-experiment

I know this is a very basic question but I am wondering if the wave function of an electron is connected to the fact the electron behaves as a wave and we have interference in the double slit experiment?

From what I understand the wave function is a function which determines the probability of finding the electron at a given point in time? I don't quite understand how this is related to the fact that electrons behave as waves in the double slit experiment? But I don't think it is a coincidence that both aspects have the word "wave" in them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wave function $\psi(x,t)$ is a complex quantity, solution of [Schrödinger's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation), which describes the state and evolution of any non-relativistic quantum system (an electron in particular). The **probability density** of finding the electron at a given spatial point $x_0$ is $|\psi(x_0,t)|^2$, which is a real quantity. The word *wave* comes from that Schrödinger's equation is in fact a wave equation for $\psi(x,t)$, so the behavior of the electron is wave-like and phenomena such as interference occur.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

At first, one needs to note that there's no **single** role of "particle" or "wave" in micro-world. Everything at micro-scale acts according to wave-particle duality principle. Hence, the [De_Broglie wave-length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave#De_Broglie_hypothesis) of *any* object which has a momentum. Trivial example, light - is it a wave or particle ? None of them, but **both**. Light interacts with matter (is absorbed, emitted, scattered) as photon *particle*, but it propagates in space as a *wave* - hence the diffraction or interference pattern you see on screen.

Same thing applies to an electron. It interacts with detector screen as a particle, but travels through slits as some sort of wave, because otherwise you would NOT see an interference pattern on electron detector. Only waves can interfere with themselves. Now, you may ask what kind of wave is that ? What we know is that wave function modulus squared is probability density of finding electron at given detector place. But there is no "deeper" understanding of wave nature of electron.

Of course it would be silly to imagine that electron somehow "splits in half" when going though both slits at once and then joins back into complete form after slits. But I guess, neither a photon is divided like that too due to slits. Particle integrity must be obeyed, because if we would imagine that electron is broken into two halfs at slits - then each one would have $0.5e$ elementary charge, which would be a complete nonsense.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from my rather lacking knowledge, electron behaving as a 'wave' is just a consequence of DeBroglie's statement that all matter exhibit wave like property. Whereas the wave function, as you said, is the probability distribution of finding that electron which behaves like a wave.
Maybe someone can put it much more formally.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.